# Subset of the complex plane with $|z^2-4z+3|\leq 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have doubts  about how I could solve this problem: sketch the set $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon |z^2-4z+3|\leq0\}$.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $|z^2 - 4z + 3| \leq 0$?

Comment: yes edit thanks

Comment: $|f(z)|\le 0 \implies f(z)=0$ use the quadratic formula and plot the two points in the solution set

Comment: mmm it's possible that $f(z)$ have real solution only?

Comment: $|z^2-4z+3|$ is a real number that is a magnitude, so it's always $\ge 0$. So when is it both $\ge 0$ and $\le 0$?

Comment: I don't know, if I consider that $|z^2-4z+3|\leq 0$ I don't have solution when I am working with $z\in\mathbb{R}$ but when I am working with $z\in\mathbb{C}$ then $z$ not exist and could I define $z$? how? In this moment should I understand that I don't have real solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possibility is clearly $|z^2-4z+3|=0$ from which you get the  points $$z={{1,3}}$$ Your set $A$ has just 2 elements.

Comment: But why 2+i? I dont know how get it

Comment: @Aryabhata: you are right. Thanks you. I edit.

Comment: @Willyf: It was a lapsus, a very distracted one because an equation of the second degree can't have four roots. I have edited.